# Unable to install backports.zoneinfo which is required to install Pillow through wheel

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm setting up my project in MacOs and needed to install requirements (including Pillow). When I run the pip3 install -r requirements.txt, everything goes fine until I receive the following message:

ERROR: Could not build wheels for backports.zoneinfo, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I've seen similar question which answers are to upgrade pip, which I did, but the error remains the same.

I'm using Python 3.10 in a venv on MacOS

Comment: backport zoneinfo does not have wheels for 3.10. U might have to use 3.9 i guess

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to get back here, but you're right. Changing it to 3.9 made the trick. Thanks.

Comment: Hey Rafael  i have added an answer pls upvote it if it was useful to you so that it can help others as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`backport zoneinfo` does not have wheels for  python3.10. So you will have to use 3.9 or lower version till the 3.10 wheels are released.

Answer (score 0):

FYI zoneinfo is part of the standard library of python since version 3.9.  Most likely you won't need backports for this library if your python version is 3.10 or higher.

Check the link
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/timezones/

> Time zone support uses zoneinfo, which is part of the Python standard
> library from Python 3.9. The backports.zoneinfo package is
> automatically installed alongside Django if you are using Python 3.8.

https://pypi.org/project/backports.zoneinfo/

> The backports.zoneinfo module should be a drop-in replacement for the
> Python 3.9 standard library module zoneinfo. If you do not support
> anything earlier than Python 3.9, you do not need this library;